# Pi Zero OTG > Mac wifi

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, macos

I've got a Pi Zero with a fresh Rasbian OTG setup working fine, but I can't seem to share my Mac's wifi with the unit. I've turned on connection sharing on the Mac, set up static IP addresses, etc etc. I've essentially followed every guide I could find online and it shows up as connected like so:

[image: settings]

Pinging the Pi from the Mac seems to work:

```
ping 192.168.7.2
PING 192.168.7.2 (192.168.7.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.169 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.168 ms
```

But pinging `google.com` from the Pi times out. Where am I going wrong?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Comment: To eliminate the obvious, did you reboot the PI?

Comment: Yeah, many times. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a decent enough answer to this is in [this](https://medium.com/@viveks3th/how-to-bootstrap-a-headless-raspberry-pi-with-a-mac-6eba3be20b26) writeup, to wit:

> On macOS, go to System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing and enable sharing internet from wifi to thunderbolt ethernet. This will begin a DHCP server to assign your PI and IP address. It will also allow your PI to access the internet through your mac once you ssh into it.